# latex beamer footer alignment

Tags: latex

How can I add text line on left side and frame number on right side of footer in latex beamer presentation?

Also, I need to exclude title page from this footer placement.

Comment: Have you done any resource?  Can you provide what you have so far?

Comment: You can set the `footline` template to suit your needs. See [Beamer: changing footline background color](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111466/5764).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

To obtain text and frame number as required, the following code is needed in the beginning.

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{text line}{text here  \hspace{3cm} \insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the frame number to the textline template, I find it easier to do it the other way round and add some text to the predefined framenumber footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\hskip1em text you want to add}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```